# Change main window implementation to user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I need to replace the following code **usercontrol instead of main window** (of course the main window is just calling to the userControl),while doing that I have the following problem.

Currently I  tried to add the following code like in the main window in the

constructor of the usercontrol after the

```
public partial class UserControl: UserControl
    {
        private static MappingViewModelView _modelViewInstance;

        public UserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _modelViewInstance = new MappingViewModelView();
            DataContext = _modelViewInstance;

            var source = Resources["source"] as CollectionViewSource;
            if (source != null)
                source.Source = _modelViewInstance.UserList;

            ListBox.SelectionChanged += listbox_SelectionChanged;
```

But now in the user control there is no event SelectionChanged for list box (using the intlisense) just `ListBox.SelectionChangedEvent` which is not fit the original solution from the main window which is

ListBox.SelectionChanged += listbox_SelectionChanged;

error which is given if i put the exact code is: Cannot access non-static event 'SelectionChanged' in static context

Any idea why the list box behave different in the user control?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public ObservableCollection<User> _UsersList = new ObservableCollection<User>();
   private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _mapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   private const string DRAG_SOURCE = "DragSource";

   public MainWindow()
   {

      InitializeComponent();
      _UsersList.Add(new User { Name = "Jhon" });
      _UsersList.Add(new User { Name = "Mike" });
      _UsersList.Add(new User { Name = "Alex" });
      _UsersList.Add(new User { Name = "Darl" });

      CollectionViewSource source = this.Resources["source"] as CollectionViewSource;
      source.Source = _UsersList;
      ListBox.SelectionChanged += listbox_SelectionChanged;

      DataObject.AddCopyingHandler(text1, DragCopy);
      DataObject.AddCopyingHandler(text2, DragCopy);
   }

   public ObservableCollection<User> UserList
   {
      get { return _UsersList; }
   }


   private void listbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
     if (e.AddedItems.Count == 1)
     {
         if (ListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
         {
            var mySelectedItem = ListBox.SelectedItem as User;
            if (mySelectedItem != null)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(ListBox, mySelectedItem,
                DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
         }
     }
   }

   private void DropText_PreviewDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
      e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
   }

   private void DropText_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
      var textbox = (TextBox)sender;

      if (!(textbox.Text.Length > 0))
      {
         DataObject data = e.Data as DataObject;
         User user = data.GetData(typeof(User)) as User;
         textbox.Tag = user;

         var name = user.Name;
         textbox.Text += name;
         textbox.Focus();
         textbox.CaretIndex = textbox.Text.Length;
         e.Handled = true;
         var remove = _UsersList.Remove((User)ListBox.SelectedItem);

         if (!_mapping.ContainsKey(textbox.Name))
             _mapping.Add(textbox.Name, name);
      }

      e.Handled = true;
   }

   private void DropText_PreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
      e.Handled = true;
   }

   private void ListBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
       DataObject data = e.Data as DataObject;
       if (data != null)
       {
           User user = data.GetData(typeof(User)) as User;
           if (user != null && !_UsersList.Contains(user))
               _UsersList.Add(user);
       }


       TextBox txtBox = e.Data.GetData(DRAG_SOURCE) as TextBox;
       if (txtBox != null)
       {
           if (_mapping.ContainsKey(txtBox.Name))
               _mapping.Remove(txtBox.Name);
           txtBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { txtBox.Text = string.Empty; }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal);
       }
       e.Handled = true; 
   }

   private void DragCopy(object sender, DataObjectCopyingEventArgs e)
   {
      if (e.IsDragDrop)
      {
         e.CancelCommand();
         TextBox txtBox = sender as TextBox;
         if (txtBox != null && txtBox.Tag != null)
         {
             DataObject dataObject = new DataObject(txtBox.Tag);
             dataObject.SetData(DRAG_SOURCE, txtBox);
             DragDrop.DoDragDrop(sender as DependencyObject, dataObject, DragDropEffects.Move | DragDropEffects.Copy);
         }
         e.Handled = true;
      }
   }

   private void DropText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      TextBox txtBox = sender as TextBox;
      if (txtBox.Text == string.Empty)
      {
         User user = txtBox.Tag as User;

         if(user != null && !_UsersList.Contains(user))
            _UsersList.Add(user);

         if (_mapping.ContainsKey(txtBox.Name))
             _mapping.Remove(txtBox.Name);
      }
   }
}


ListBox x:Name="ListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="115"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource source}}" 
                     DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                     AllowDrop="True" Drop="ListBox_Drop" />

<Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="source">
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>



        <TextBox x:Name="text1"  
                  AcceptsReturn="True"
                  AllowDrop="True" 
                  PreviewDragEnter="DropText_PreviewDragEnter"
                  PreviewDrop="DropText_PreviewDrop"
                  PreviewDragOver="DropText_PreviewDragOver"
                  TextChanged="DropText_TextChanged"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

        <TextBox x:Name="text2"  
                  AcceptsReturn="True"
                  AllowDrop="True" 
                  PreviewDragEnter="DropText_PreviewDragEnter"
                  PreviewDrop="DropText_PreviewDrop"
                  PreviewDragOver="DropText_PreviewDragOver"
                  TextChanged="DropText_TextChanged"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Comment: Have you moved the ListBox to the UserControl? If so, have you changed the name of the ListBox? If not, do you want the UserControl to react to the selection change of the ListBox in the Main window?

Comment: @Markus- OF course I have remove the list box to the user control XAML and dont change the name.I want that the main window just call to the user control and remove the logic of the main window to the user control

Comment: Is your UserControl name is really `UserControl`? or it is just here in the example code? writing only this line: `public partial class UserControl: UserControl` will cause a `Circular base class dependency involving` compiler error and break the build. I wonder how you can even build your project.

Comment: @Markus- please propose your comment as answer I wnat to give you the points since i didnt figure out the name was changed (capital latter) .....thank you very much

Comment: @mileyH good to hear that it helped. I've added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you moved the ListBox to the UserControl, the most likely reasen is that - maybe by accident - the name was changed in the process.
The error message points in this direction as it recognizes ListBox as the type and not as the name of a concrete instance of a ListBox on the UserControl.

Comment: hi marcus , i have another issue and open new post in few min ,please see if you can assist,thanks

Comment: @mileyH: I will (but it may take some time)